# Signing for "xyzApp" requires a development team

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I got a project from bitbucket, I cloned it but in General->Signing section "Signing for "xyzApp" requires a development team." message is showing. Please suggest what changes to be made so that I can make a build.

[image]

Comment: You need a developer account if you are going to use APNs (Apple Push Notifications).

Comment: To simply run application, you can turn off push notification/remote notification from capabilities. Uncheck "Automatically manage signing" and run with any wild card profile.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for the mac and you are not going to publish on mac app store, you do not need a developer account.

You do need an account for any of the following:

- Install an app on an iOS device (even your own one for debugging)
- Publish an app on any of the app stores (either iOS or Mac)

Edit: note that if you do not have an account, your Os X applications will be unsigned. They'll work, but each of your users will get a warning and will need to lower the security settings of his Mac in order to be able to run the application (or, at least, he'll have to approve each application specifically).

-->Remove checkbox (AUTOMATICALLY MANAGE SIGNING) and run in Simulator

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to run the app on real iOS device then you can uncheck "Automatically manage signing" and run this app over iPhone Simulator.**

If you want to run this app on real iOS device or publish app on App-store, you should have apple developer account and need to follow these steps:

1. Add new app to App-store-connect first with your bundle identifier.
   https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808728-iOS-Adding-a-New-App-in-AppStore-Connect
2. Create new iOS signing certificate for distribution and develop
   https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003458931-Creating-the-iOS-Distribution-Certificate
3. Create App provisioning profile, development and distribution, for your app 
   https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-ios/
4. Download and install signing certificate and provisioning profile on your mac and rebuild your app from Xcode.

That's it now you can install and run your application on provisioned iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for reply.